# Google Services Version Conflict after adding FCM Plugin : ionic 3

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-play-services

I try to use the FCM plugin, but my ideas all failed:

Case 1: I added cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated with cordova-google-plus plugin which is causing the Cordova build to fail:

[image: screenshot]

Case 2: I commented following lines in fcmplugin.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'   
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin'
```

Then I added following lines into project build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of build.gradle
```

Cordova Build Successful but app not running on device/emulator("App has stopped").

Plugins used in my app:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Remove android platform
on FCMPlugin.gradle (plugin folder) edit like this:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

Then on plugin.xml file

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4" />
```